# For each column create unique workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet and I want each column to be stored in different workbook.

```
Zone    State
North   Punjab
North   Haryana
South   Kerala
South   Chennai
```

O/p : should be two excel workbook with zone in one book and State in another

With this code I am able to copy content to new sheet in existing workbook but not in new workbook.

```
Sub CopyUnique()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Main")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Count")
    s1.Range("B:B").Copy s2.Range("A1")
    s2.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Comment: try adding `s2.Move` in the end of your code before `End Sub`

Comment: i am saving it in new worksheet only..not in new workbook. May be that's the problem because s2.move is not working

Comment: Did it give you an Error ? `s2.Move` ?

Comment: it did nothing..

Comment: It should move your worksheet to a new workbook. Wonder why nothing is happening.

Comment: it did moved to new workbook. I had changed the name of sheets, that's why I was having problem.
Is it possible to ask number of columns from user and move those columns to new workbooks.

Comment: Yes ... Almost every manipulation is possible using VBA, all you have to do is formulate a logic for it to perform the desired task.

Comment: Can you suggest me some links where manipulation is possible as per user input. This is something new to me.

Comment: You can use [InputBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) to get input from the user for the column numbers, then use the same code to copy those columns on a new or other sheet. And finally using the `.Move` to move it to new workbook.

Comment: by s2.move it do move it to new workbook. how to save that workbook at any specified location.

Comment: Add this line After `s2.Move` ..... `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\mohit.bansal\Desktop\Test\New.xlsx")` .. Just change the Path as you need.

Comment: See  the answer Below, if you still not able to do it

Comment: Thanks...I wasn't providing the path..I thought it will get automatically stored at the same location where this file is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Below Code:

```
Sub CopyUnique()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Main")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Count")
    s1.Range("B:B").Copy s2.Range("A1")
    s2.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo


    s2.Move

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\--------\Desktop\Test\New.xlsx")

    'If you want close that workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True

End Sub
```

Comment: Similar Answer: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609829/user-will-enter-range-of-columns-and-each-column-will-be-saved-in-a-new-workbook/56609890?noredirect=1#comment99794790_56609890)