# User will enter range of columns and each column will be saved in a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

User will select the column range they want separate sheets

```
Sub CopyUnique()

    Dim NewCode As Range
    Set NewCode = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the column with the code numbers", Title:="New Event Selector", Type:=8)
    Dim s2 As Worksheet
    With NewCode
        For currentColumn = 1 To .Columns.Count Step 1
            Set s2 = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            s2.Name = "New.currentColumn"
            NewCode.Copy _
            Destination:=s2.Range("A1")
            s2.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
            s2.Move
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Chatbot\Output\Wb.xlsx")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
         Next currentColumn

    End With


End Sub
```

My output is creating only one sheet, whereas I want **unique workbook** for each column selected.

Comment: Because you are moving all the Columns together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

Now it will copy only one column at a time, and also save the workbooks in the same path with different names. I have added counting 1,2,3.... etc at the end of name.

```
Sub CopyUnique()

    Dim NewCode As Range
    Set NewCode = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the column with the code numbers", Title:="New Event Selector", Type:=8)
    Dim s2 As Worksheet
    With NewCode
        For currentcolumn = 1 To .Columns.Count Step 1
            Set s2 = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            s2.Name = "New.currentColumn"
            NewCode.Columns(currentcolumn).Copy _
            Destination:=s2.Range("A1")
            s2.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
            s2.Move
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Chatbot\Output\Wb" & currentcolumn & ".xlsx")
            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
         Next currentcolumn

    End With


End Sub
```

You can change as per your need.